# create/update/subscribe pattern : Orion --> cygnus Fiware

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I would like to create and then update an entity regularly. And then subscribe to modifications, sending these modifs to my runnning fiware-cygnus handler ( via http notify).

Is it possible to use a running orion instance (i.e. http://orion.lab.fiware.org:1026) to experiment this Use Case?

Thanks phil

Answer (score 0):

All the information you need is [in the documentation](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org). In particular:

- [How to create an entity](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/walkthrough_apiv1/index.html#entity-creation)
- [How to update an entity](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/walkthrough_apiv1/index.html#update-context-elements)
- [How to subscribe](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/walkthrough_apiv1/index.html#context-subscriptions) (general information)
- [How to connect Cygnus to Orion](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/user_and_programmer_guide/connecting_orion.md) (Cygnus specific documentation)